# Convert SQL file in Javascript Object in node.js

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have to convert a SQL script and anybody knows any `node.js` package that converts this in JavaScript Object?

***Follow example :***

```
Insert into People values ('John',20)
```

**Converts to:**

```
{name: 'john', age:20}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to create your custom module by yourself.
no npm for this purpose.